# Loading an Alert Box from a Thread when the activity has gone away

Tags: android

I have a comment activity that loads a Thread and sends some data to a server; the activity is immediately finished once the submit button is pressed.

The user is then free to do other things in my application.

When the server responds an `AlertDialog` is shown.

The problem is that since the initial context has been destroyed, my application crashes.

I tried `getApplicationContext()` but still get an exception.

Answer (score 4):

Put your network stuff in a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), then show a [status bar notification](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/index.html#StatusBar) instead of a dialog.

Comment: This is not a bad idea actually.  I may go this route if I cannot find another way around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

From JavaDocs:
AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

Comment: I can do this but I still have the context problem.  I pass the context to the Threaded task.